# Vmware: how do I share directories between Ununtu (guest) and Mac host using nfs?

Tags: linux, vmware, mount, nfs

I am trying to share a directory between an ubuntu vm and a mac host. I tried 
`mount -t nfs 192.168.95.151:/path-to-directory ~/mounttest` But this results in a `connection refused` message. I am not sure if what I am doing is the right way to go about it.

Comment: You could try adding credentials with flag `-o username=youruser,password=yourpassword`

Comment: Which OS is 192.168.95.151? You're running `mount` on the OSX host and trying to mount a folder shared from the ubuntu guest? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it it will help, but when I am running Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager from windows, I need to setup the VM software for my host to share the drive to the VM first, before I can mount it in my VM.
I use Shared Folders here on it.